# Singleton application with vector member

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, compiler-optimization, race-condition

I have a Singleton application server (assume being created correctly). The server class has a non static vector member which is modified in several methods. Is it possible that the compiler optimizes the code such that the vector is modified non serially across several request processing method chains. I mean can two chains of method calls may intersect across different requests ?
I think they can because the method calls would be jumps to labels .

Comment: No. However, it is very possible that you have several threads that modify the same data concurrently. You should therefore protect said data with a Mutex.

Comment: @FélixCantournet If your answer is NO , then why need a mutext to synchronize ? Vector is thread safe . What I am asking is say the first thread is putting objects into the singleton.vector_mem and second thread is removing , then they can possibly cross each other .

Comment: My answer is No "the compiler cannot do this". But you most assuredly can. You say you have a race condition, but you don't seem to be aware of multithreading, so I'm just pointing this out to you.

Comment: @FélixCantournet Sorry... Trying to explain a few missing msgs out of a million in a world where everything seems singleton makes u inarticulate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seeing your comments I'm posting an answer because something needs to be clear : std containers are **not** "threadsafe".

They provide **some** protection and garantees, like the fact that you can have multiple *readers* safely.
However you **cannot** have multiple writers, or writers and readers concurrently.

Regarding your question : the compiler is not guilty.
Given your comment I suppose you have conccurent writes and reads on your std::vector which is where you have a problem right now.
Just add a mutex, and check if the performance isn't too horrid. If it is look for another datastructure/architecture.